# How can I use specific links and emails for an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, email

Is it possible for the link box in an HTML form to accept only links from a specific website? This is the code of the box.

HTML:

```html
<label class="Link"> Link to Tool:</label>
        <input type="url" id="Approval" Placeholder="Tool Link">
```

Also I would like the email box to accept emails only from a specific company how could I do this?
I have made this code but it accepts only @company.com emails I would like it to also accept from other countries such as @company.fr, @company.gr etc.

```html
<label class="Email"> Email:</label>
        <input type="email" Placeholder="Email" id="Email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@company\.com$" required>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var input = document.getElementById("Email");
        input.oninvalid = function(event) {
            event.target.setCustomValidity("Please provide an @company email.")
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: For the email you could add all the `fr`, `gr` etc ... between parenthesis like that : `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@company\.(com|fr|gr)$` (also keep in mind that you can't trust html : similar verifications are necessary in your backend language)

Comment: For the link this pattern should work : `^https?:\/\/(www\.)?company\.(fr|en|gr|com)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **link** this pattern should work : `^https?:\/\/(www\.)?company\.(fr|en|gr|com)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$`.

- `?` is to allow the previous rule to be null
- `()` to catch a group of rules
- don't forget `-` so link like http://company.com/contact-us will work to.

For the **email** you could add all the `fr`, `gr` etc ... between parenthesis like that : `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@company\.(com|fr|gr)$`. The `|` is for `OR`.

(also keep in mind that you can't trust html : similar verifications are necessary in your backend language)

Comment: Thank you that's very useful as I am new in to programming! :)